# Parallel task in Hangfire Recurring Job

Tags: c#, .net, service, hangfire, topshelf

I need to run parallel tasks inside of an recurring job fired every minute by Hangfire.

Tried Task Factory which starts the task but never waits for the actual execution to complete.

Parallel Foreach also does the same.

Comment: It would be awesome if you could share a [mcve].

Comment: Why not just `Wait()` the task produced by StartNew, or just Task.WaitAll the list of tasks you have started ? Or loop until `Parallel.ForEach()` result `IsCompleted` ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Result property from Task, it will wait your process run and get the process value.

Other way, is use async await, but your process it's have to be asynchronous.

I hope I have helped you.

Comment: Hi souzaMateus - and welcome to Stack Overflow! Please can you add a little more detail to your answer, perhaps an example bit of code to explain how this all works?

Answer (score 0):

This isn't really hangfire related but if you want to run some things in parallel you can use something similar to below:

```cs
public void Test() {
    List<Task> tasks = new List<Task>();
    tasks.Add(Task.Run(() => {
        // your code here 
    }));

    tasks.Add(Task.Run(() =>
    {
        // your other parallel code here
    }));
    Task.WhenAll(tasks).Wait();
}
```

If your using a newer version of hangfire it supports async method for background jobs so you just change the last line to `await Task.WhenAll(tasks);`.